# How to reload or refresh a Windowsphone User Control in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am making a windowsphone silverlight App for windowsphone OS 8. I am Using windowsphone user controls where I make changes dynamically.
My question is just like the way we create an instance of a phoneApplication Page for Normal .xaml Page using NavigationService.Navigate("Source Uri with unique GUID") . How can I achieve the same effect for a windowsphone User Control Page where I make my dynamic changes to update as there is no Navigation Service.Navigate() method available. ?
Currently I have to Navigate like UserControl-Page-UserControl

Comment: Can you add more details, and maybe sample code you've tried that didn't work? Likely you just need to remove the old control from the tree and add a new instance programmatically, but without knowing exactly what you want to do it's hard to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to Navigate from a page, you can use NavigationService.Navigate().

When you want to Navigate from a UserControl, You can use the PhoneApplicationFrame to navigate.

Code Sample:

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/MyProjectName;component/MyFolderName/MyPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

You need to append a GUID when you want to navigate to a new instance of the same page which you are currently residing.

Comment: It is typically a design error if you need to force a new page via a GUID; the page should use its parameters to distinguish the contents. If you just want to refresh the current page, you should use an MVVM approach.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Peter. If you have distinguished parameters there is no need for a GUID to be appended to the navigation uri; the concept is that Navigation Uri should be different in order to create a new instance of the page. @Aman explain your complete scenario so that you can get better approach for your question.

Comment: @PradeepAJ Peter thats what I am trying to do.Creating a new instance of Page